# Removing the comma between Attribute Option and Attribute Price in Ubercart for Drupal 7

Tags: ubercart

[image: Ubercart for Drupal 7: Attribute Options separated from label by comma]

Discovering Product Attributes in Ubercart was quite a find. However, my client does not like the way the dropdown looks. Previously, all the prices had + in front of them, but I was able to remove them taking a clue from questions by other Drupal users (sites/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.module line 1361). But, finding where to get rid of the comma eludes me.

If you have any further clues, I would be most appreciative!

Answer (score 1):

`theme_uc_attribute_option($option, $price)` is what you're looking for. Override that theme function in your theme and you can eliminate the "," & the price adjustment amount.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clue! For anyone who is new to the Drupal file structure, I found the function that Shawn mentioned in sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute.theme.inc. The file I was looking in was sites/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.module. So, obviously, I couldn't find it because I was in the wrong place.

Now, I will admit that while I have worked extensively in the some basic theme files, I have never worked in Drupal functions. I know from best practices in WordPress that you should not override anything in original files, if possible. Where do I go to override?

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that will come in handing for other functions as well!

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7, Ubercart 3...

Go to:
admin/store/settings/products > Attribute settings

Tick "Display total price" and save.

Answer (score 0):

Add span and Class in the file uc_attribute.theme.inc under function theme_uc_attribute_option like shown below..and apply your class or style to it
$output .= ' ' . $variables['price'].'';

Comment: Hi @urvesh, welcome to Drupal Answers. To improve your answer, please describe how one can hook into `theme_uc_attribute_option()` in a custom theme's `template.php` for example instead of altering the contributed module. Thanks!